# welcome page before main page (home page)

Tags: 7

How do I redirect the users who want to visit my site to a PHP page that has a link to index.php?

When someone go to example.com they should see a PHP page (e.g. a welcome page) where they would find a link to access the front page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Modules**

You could accomplish this with the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module and add granular control over who sees the splash page and when.

**Additional Details**

Create a new rule. (admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/add)

React on Event: Drupal is initializing

Condition: Execute Custom PHP Code

```
$homepage = FALSE;
if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
  $homepage = TRUE;
}
return $homepage;
```

Action: Page Redirect

**Drupal Rules Exported Rule**

This can be copy and pasted into the Rules Import menu. (admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/import)

```
{ "rules_show_splash_page" : {
    "LABEL" : "Show Splash Page",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "TAGS" : [ "splashpage" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "php", "rules" ],
    "ON" : [ "init" ],
    "IF" : [
      { "php_eval" : { "code" : "$homepage = FALSE;\r\nif (drupal_is_front_page()) {\r\n  $homepage = TRUE;\r\n}\r\nreturn $homepage;" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "redirect" : { "url" : "splash-page-url" } } ]
  }
}
```

Tested and working on my dev site.

Comment: thank you too, i tried your way but it's the same, it's redirect to the splah page everu time visitor go to home page of my site.  i just want to redirect once when open the site for the first time

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy to go down the module route, the following should get you started.

You're going to want to set a cookie to see if the user has been to the site before.  If the cookie is set, then you know the user has been to your site ebfore and it shouldn't redirect to the splash page.

```
function MYMODULE_init() {
  if (!isset($_COOKIE['mysite_firstvisit'])) {
    drupal_goto('path/to/splash/page');
    setcookie('mysite_firstvisit', '1');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This project is in alpha, but the [Splashify](http://drupal.org/project/splashify) project may be what you're looking for.

Comment: i can't install this module in my site because it's incompatible with version 7.x-1.0

Comment: What version of Drupal are you running?

Comment: drupal version 7.14

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about a [Splash Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splash_screen) (or "splash page").

I only know of one module that has such functionality for Drupal 7 (there was the [Splash](http://drupal.org/project/splash) module for Drupal 6 but it hasn't been ported), and that's [ThemeKey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey). One of the features that you can apparently "easily achieve" is:

> a front-page / "splash" screen

Comment: i installed the modules but i did not knwo how to make it, can you put me in the right way?

Comment: Both of the modules you list link to the Splash project page... the actual link to ThemeKey is [here](http://drupal.org/project/themekey).

Comment: Help for ThemeKey (once installed) is at /admin/help/themekey. There's a decent screencast at [MustardSeed](http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode52), although I don't know if it covers splash screens.

Comment: @abd See the link from EmmyS

Comment: thank you guys for your help, but what i want exactly is redirect to the splash page just for the first time the visitor ask my site, then it should go back to the original home page when click on the logo of mysite.

Answer (score 0):

I added a page--front.tpl.php in my theme. Drupal picks that up as a splash screen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918936/page-front-tpl-php-not-working-in-drupal-7